# Sharing Credit/Reputation For a 'Joint' Answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Has there ever been a system tried whereby two (or possibly more) users could ***share*** credit for an answer?

For example, it seems that 'near-simultaneous' answers aren't that rare (especially for popular tags); and, often, two such answers may both be 'equally correct', 'equally good`, or even 'equally acceptable' to the question's OP.

Rather than encouraging 'competition' between those two answerers, could a system be devised whereby (by mutual consent) the two users agree on the text/content of a 'merged' answer and post that as a replacement.

Reputation credits for upvotes and 'acceptance' could then be split between the contributors. (Exactly how the mathematics would work is a detail, here.)

This may very well produce a better overall answer! It would also reduce 'clogging', and take away a (sometimes difficult) choice for the OP (especially for new users).

After all, duplicate questions are vehemently chased down - why not duplicate answers?

Comment: In the event of 'near-simultaneous' answers its easy enough for one of the anwserers to improve their answer to improve upon it making it technically the same but more valuable in the end.

Comment: I would rather see 5 answers for 5 different solutions or 5 same answers using different explanations than one huge amalgamation of everything.

Comment: @DaImTo So, I could post a rubbish answer and then, later, 'improve' it by taking bits and pieces out of others' efforts? That's called "Plagiarism" in my book! (Well, technically, it's not actually *my* book but …)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Generally, I agree. But there are cases where two answer are ***very*** similar, or have a large overlap. These are the cases I had in mind.

Comment: @Adrian you said **'near-simultaneous' 'equally correct'** thats not **near-simultaneous' 'equally correct'** in my book.   If your going to post a rubbish answer then it will be downvoted its not an issue.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, but there's nothing stopping me abusing the system for non-simul or non-correct answers. I did add "by mutual consent" in my posit.

Comment: Generally, yes. Also best not using swear words, with or wihout obfuscation ;-)

Comment: PS: As a newcomer to the Meta site: Am I correct in assuming 'down votes' don't have quite the same meaning as on the main site? Otherwise, I'd have long since nuked this one! (I'm assuming downvotes are saying: We disagree with this idea, rather than saying: We think this is a rubbish post.) [[Reposted as too late to edit.]]

Comment: @Adrian Correct

Comment: @Nick - Cool! And, HEY - I got an UPVOTE! (Hehehe...)

Comment: Are you basically suggesting [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) posts but with rep?

Comment: @Script47 That may be one way to go. But how would the rep work? There's lots of folks who don't want to lose that, I gather (I've encountered various less-than-polite phrases for such). But is there no level possible between 'individual User' and 'Community'?

Comment: To those who would want to take part if something like this, I think the sharing of rep is too important a detail to be waved away as a detail. But that's a guess -- I don't care about rep enough to know how the motivation works.

Comment: @HereticMonkey By 'detail' I just meant the exact maths. So, for an 'accept`, would each/every participant get +15 rep, or would that be divided among them (bad). One would obviously need a balance - as you say, rep is very important to many on SO.

Comment: How would administration of this work? Using comments to communicate consensus building would add more clogging/noise so another channel would be needed for communication. What about disagreements? A 5-10 minute effort on an initial answer could turn into significant time investment to work out merge issues. Multiple similar answers can also be beneficial to some people....as affirmation of an approach being common

Comment: @charlietfl Well, just as an off-the-cuff idea: Once provisional agreement to merge had been made, then editing could be done by each user and subject to review by the other(s). The basic mechanism for consensus-editing already exists.

Comment: @charlietfl As for: "as affirmation of an approach being common" then multi-name accreditation would surely show the same.

Comment: Just trying to point out there are  side effects that have to be considered also that could be time consuming and conflicts that could arise as a result

Comment: @Everybody: It was, after all, just a suggestion. Not an especially popular one, though, it would seem. And, of course, it would never be without its own new issues.

Comment: @Adrian to be more specific on votes - they do mean the same as on main except for post that are "feature-requests" or look like one (you've presumably read explanation of that tag before using it)… Unfortunately there is no way to represent "you did not even look up for existing information" from "I don't think this proposal need to be implemented". I personally think this is reasonably unique proposal but I have no particular opinion about whether we should call to implement it - so no votes from me here.

Comment: @Adrian on "I could post a rubbish answer and then, later, 'improve' it by taking bits and pieces out of others' efforts" - sure, search "Fastest Gun In The North West" on meta for the discussions. Summary: you gain reputation points as well as reputation of being @#$@ - using non-unique name can help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of this site is not to build *a perfectly fair reputation system*. The main purpose is to build up a *collection of knowledge*. So let's take *reputation* out of the equation. It's a tool to reach goals, not a goal itself.

Under that perspective, your proposal of *merging nearly identical answers* has mainly one benefit: 
It cleans up threads with a lot of answers, if you merge identical answers you can find different answers more easily.

Now the question is, isn't that possible with the tools we already have?

We do have (1) community wikis were contributors are encouraged to edit an existing answer instead of creating another one, and (2) answerers can delete their own answers and upvote the other one, in the case that the other is *covering the same points* or even *slightly better*.

So what would your proposal change? It would basically do the same as (2) and (1), but it has both it's benefits ...

[+] It would encourage more people to "clean up" answer threads, as they might gain more reputation by merging with a higher voted answer.

... and it's downsides ...

[-] It might encourage answerers to copy existing answers, just to then request a merge (might allow abuse of the reputation system).

[-] Instead of having different perspectives on the same topic, it encourages *one right final merged answer* (Is there one?). We loose all those nuances.

So all in all, I don't think this is a good idea.

> two such answers may both be 'equally correct', 'equally good`, or even 'equally acceptable' to the question's OP.

Sure. I don't see a problem here. The OP got his answer, no matter which one he finally chooses as "correct". And over time, votes will move the best answer to the top.

> After all, duplicate questions are vehemently chased down

*But* duplicates *aren't merged*, they *are linked*. Or in other words: Multiple *duplicate* questions get linked to the *same answers*. Duplicates aren't "chased down" to remove them, they get *ordered*. Through the duplicate system, no matter how you word your problem when searching for it, someone used (nearly) the same words before in one of those questions all directing to the same set of answers.